# Constructing expressions using Sum vs Array[... Plus] vs Plus@@Table[...]

Tags: functions, list-manipulation, built-in-symbols, expression-construction, benchmarking

For constructing a sum of terms which are symbolic, I noticed that in addition to

```
Sum[f[i],{i,1,10}]

(* f[1] + f[2] + f[3] + f[4] + f[5] + f[6] + f[7] + f[8] + f[9] + f[10] *)
```

I can also do

```
Array[f,10,1,Plus]

(* f[1] + f[2] + f[3] + f[4] + f[5] + f[6] + f[7] + f[8] + f[9] + f[10] *)
```

or even `Plus@@Table[f[i],{i,1,10}]` or `Total[Table[f[i],{i,1,10}]]`.

While it is not a huge surprise I'm able to achieve the same result using different functions in *Mathematica*, I'm wondering if there are specific use cases which prefers one form over another for the construction of a sum of symbolic terms.  Right now all I can think of for `Array` is that there the local iterator `i` is not needed.  But performance/memory-wise, is there something else I should be aware of?

Comment: Michael Trott in Programming (pp 707 - 710)  argues that as Table has the attribute HoldAll it computes its argument for every call, whereas Array "to the extent possible" computes its argument only at the beginning. _This may lead to differences in behaviour as well as speed_. Compare (example given by MT) `a = 0; Table[a = a + 1; ToExpression[StringJoin["a" <> ToString[a]]][i, j], {i, 3}, {j, 3}]` to `a = 0; Array[a = a + 1; ToExpression[StringJoin["a" <> ToString[a]]], {3, 3}]`. [Old SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5764774/499167)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is something that you could have tested yourself, quite easily. I sugest the use of [`RepeatedTiming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RepeatedTiming.html) for more reliable measurements.

```
BarChart[
 {
   First@RepeatedTiming[
     Sum[f[i], {i, 1, 100}]
     ],
   First@RepeatedTiming[
     Array[f, 100, 1, Plus]
     ],
   First@RepeatedTiming[
     Total@Table[f[i], {i, 1, 100}]
     ],
   First@RepeatedTiming[
     Plus @@ Table[f[i], {i, 1, 100}]
     ],
   First@RepeatedTiming[
     Plus @@ (f /@ Range[100])
     ],
   First@RepeatedTiming[
     Total[f /@ Range[100]]
     ]
   } 10^6
 , ChartLabels -> {
   "Sum",
   "Array[_,Plus]",
   "Total@Table",
   "Plus@@Table",
   "Plus@@Range",
   "Total-Range"
   }
 , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
 , AspectRatio -> 1/2
 , FrameLabel -> {"Method", "Time \[Mu]s"}
 , ImageSize -> 600
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Ok, that's interesting data.  It seems to support the use of `Array` in the simplest case of `f`.  Having this result can be useful to others.  I'm also looking answers from seasoned/experienced programmers as well.

Comment: @QuantumDot it will also depend on the auto-compilation and whether your arrays and things are packed, although I still expect `Array` to do best there. Also of interest might be a `Fold[#+f[#2]&, ...]` type thing, although if all is as I expect that will be slowest.

Comment: `f /@ Range[100]` is more efficient than `Table[f[i], {i, 1, 100}]` with either `Total` or `Plus`

Comment: @BobHanlon, OK, I included that in the comparison.

Answer (score 6):

`Sum` isn't really for constructing expressions: it's primarily for finding an analytic formula that represents a sum. It's mostly useful when bounds are unknown or infinite:

```
Sum[1/2^i, {i, 1, n}]
(* 2^-n (-1 + 2^n) *)
```

Mere expression construction can't do this.