# How to create non-rectangular array with Array?

Tags: functions, function-construction, list-manipulation, built-in-symbols

From the answers to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/176372/2048), I learned that the recommended way to construct a symbolic sum of terms in an expression is to use `Array`.

But I'm having a little trouble creating a non-rectangular array with it.  For example, how do I emulate something like

```
Table[f[i,j],{i,1,5},{j,i,5}]
Sum[f[i,j],{i,1,5},{j,i,5}]
```

which have pyramidal forms?

Is `Array` simply inflexible about the shape of the output.  If so, what is the recommended method to construct a non-rectangular array?

---

I suppose I can nest `Array` like so:

```
Array[Function[{i}, Array[f[i, #] &, 6 - i, i, Plus]], 5, 1, Plus]
```

But I have to use a named function with argument `i` in order for it to work. Is it possible to achieve the same result using anonymous functions only?

Comment: Out of curiosity, I have tried this : `Array[If[#2 >= #1,f[#1,#2],Nothing]&,{5,5}]`. it seems to work. Maybe stupid.

Comment: @andre I guess it works for Lists but for my case, I need head Plus, for which Nothing doesn’t work.

Answer (score 7):

Using the [*vanishing function* ( ##&[])](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3705/125)  or `Unevaluated @ Sequence[]` combined with `If` or `Piecewise`:

```
Array[If[# <= #2, f@##, ## &[]] &, {3, 3}, 1, foo]
```

> foo[foo[f[1, 1], f[1, 2], f[1, 3]], foo[f[2, 2], f[2, 3]], foo[f[3, 3]]]

```
Array[If[# <= #2, f @ ##, ## &[]] &, {3, 3}, 1, Plus]
```

> f[1, 1] + f[1, 2] + f[1, 3] + f[2, 2] + f[2, 3] + f[3, 3]

```
Array[If[# <= #2, f @ ##, ## &[]] &, {3, 3}, 1, Times]
```

> f[1, 1] f[1, 2] f[1, 3] f[2, 2] f[2, 3] f[3, 3]

Alternatively, use `##&[]` as the default value in `Piecewise`:

```
Array[Piecewise[{{f @ ##, # <= #2}}, ## &[]] &, {3, 3}, 1, Plus]
```

> f[1, 1] + f[1, 2] + f[1, 3] + f[2, 2] + f[2, 3] + f[3, 3]

```
Array[Piecewise[{{f @ ##, # <= #2}}, ## &[]] &, {3, 3}, 1, Times]
```

> f[1, 1] f[1, 2] f[1, 3] f[2, 2] f[2, 3] f[3, 3]

In both cases, using `Unevaluated @ Sequence[]` in place of `##&[]` also works.

Answer (score 6):

Your `Table` command doesn't produce an array,

```
Table[f[i, j], {i, 1, 5}, {j, i, 5}] // ArrayQ
(* False *)
```

`Array` seems like wrong tool for this job, but with the versatility of the language we can make it work.

`Array` is going to make a rectangular array, so if we want to drop terms we can set them equal to `Nothing` if we want a list structure in the end, or to `0` if we want them to drop out of a sum.  You could do this either by adding a `DownValue` for `f`,

```
f[i_, j_] /; i > j := 0;
Array[f, {3, 3}, 1, Plus]
(* f[1, 1] + f[1, 2] + f[1, 3] + f[2, 2] + f[2, 3] + f[3, 3] *)
```

or by using a replacement rule,

```
ClearAll@f
Array[f, {3, 3}] /. f[i_, j_] /; i > j :> Nothing
(* {{f[1, 1], f[1, 2], f[1, 3]}, {f[2, 2], f[2, 3]}, {f[3, 3]}} *)
```

For this task though, any performance gain you get from `Array` is lost due to the evaluation step of throwing away half the values.  `Table` still seems like the right choice for constructing a non-rectangular array:

```
nmax = 500;

sum1 = 
   Array[f, {nmax, nmax}, 1, Plus] /. 
    f[i_, j_] /; i > j :> 0; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.309, Null} *)

sum2 = 
   Array[If[# <= #2, f@##, ## &[]] &, {nmax, nmax}, 1, 
    Plus]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.31, Null} *)

sum3 = 
   Plus @@ Flatten[
     Table[f[i, j], {i, 1, nmax}, {j, i, nmax}]]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.057, Null} *)

SameQ[sum1, sum2, sum3]
(* True *)
```

Comment: And what about if I want to make a sum of terms (using `Plus` as the last argument of `Array`)?

Comment: @QuantumDot - You could just use `f[i_, j_] /; i > j := 0; Array[f, {5, 5}, 1, Plus]`, or if you'd rather not have down values, `Array[f, {5, 5}, 1, Plus] /. f[i_, j_] /; i > j :> 0`